PA TO Base 64 without flow
With({
    InputText:"Happy Holidays",
    AsciiTable:AddColumns(Sequence(2^8,1),"char",Char(Value)),
    B64ToBin:
    Table(
        {b64:"A",bin:"000000"},
        {b64:"B",bin:"000001"},
        {b64:"C",bin:"000010"},
        {b64:"D",bin:"000011"},
        {b64:"E",bin:"000100"},
        {b64:"F",bin:"000101"},
        {b64:"G",bin:"000110"},
        {b64:"H",bin:"000111"},
        {b64:"I",bin:"001000"},
        {b64:"J",bin:"001001"},
        {b64:"K",bin:"001010"},
        {b64:"L",bin:"001011"},
        {b64:"M",bin:"001100"},
        {b64:"N",bin:"001101"},
        {b64:"O",bin:"001110"},
        {b64:"P",bin:"001111"},
        {b64:"Q",bin:"010000"},
        {b64:"R",bin:"010001"},
        {b64:"S",bin:"010010"},
        {b64:"T",bin:"010011"},
        {b64:"U",bin:"010100"},
        {b64:"V",bin:"010101"},
        {b64:"W",bin:"010110"},
        {b64:"X",bin:"010111"},
        {b64:"Y",bin:"011000"},
        {b64:"Z",bin:"011001"},
        {b64:"a",bin:"011010"},
        {b64:"b",bin:"011011"},
        {b64:"c",bin:"011100"},
        {b64:"d",bin:"011101"},
        {b64:"e",bin:"011110"},
        {b64:"f",bin:"011111"},
        {b64:"g",bin:"100000"},
        {b64:"h",bin:"100001"},
        {b64:"i",bin:"100010"},
        {b64:"j",bin:"100011"},
        {b64:"k",bin:"100100"},
        {b64:"l",bin:"100101"},
        {b64:"m",bin:"100110"},
        {b64:"n",bin:"100111"},
        {b64:"o",bin:"101000"},
        {b64:"p",bin:"101001"},
        {b64:"q",bin:"101010"},
        {b64:"r",bin:"101011"},
        {b64:"s",bin:"101100"},
        {b64:"t",bin:"101101"},
        {b64:"u",bin:"101110"},
        {b64:"v",bin:"101111"},
        {b64:"w",bin:"110000"},
        {b64:"x",bin:"110001"},
        {b64:"y",bin:"110010"},
        {b64:"z",bin:"110011"},
        {b64:"0",bin:"110100"},
        {b64:"1",bin:"110101"},
        {b64:"2",bin:"110110"},
        {b64:"3",bin:"110111"},
        {b64:"4",bin:"111000"},
        {b64:"5",bin:"111001"},
        {b64:"6",bin:"111010"},
        {b64:"7",bin:"111011"},
        {b64:"8",bin:"111100"},
        {b64:"9",bin:"111101"},
        {b64:"+",bin:"111110"},
        {b64:"/",bin:"111111"}
    )},
    With({
    BinRep:
    Concat(
        AddColumns(ForAll(Split(InputText,""), {Result: ThisRecord.Value}),"dec",LookUp(AsciiTable,char=Result).Value),//Convert text to Ascii character code (decimal)
        Concat(Sequence(8,8,-1),Text(If(And(Mod(dec,Power(2,Value))>=Power(2,Value-1),Mod(dec,Power(2,Value))<Power(2,Value)),1,0)))&"","")//Convert decimal to binary
    },
        With({b64string:Concat(
            Sequence(
                RoundUp(Len(BinRep)/6,0),0),
                LookUp(
                    B64ToBin,
                    bin=Mid(BinRep&Left("000000",6-Mod(Len(BinRep),6)),6*Value+1,6) //Left("000000"....) is padding right with zero
                ).b64&"", 
                ""
            )},
            b64string&Left("====",Mod(4-Mod(Len(b64string),4),4))//Convert binary to base64
        )
    )
)


Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
